# how to ignore a character in the regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I do not know how to ignore an item from the ER.

just need to get P1, but this returns /P1.

is possible to just ignore the bar?

```
$pattern = "#(/P[0-9])?#";
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly? what strings should match , what parts should be returned ? can you give examples

Comment: move the '/' outside of the (group).

Comment: The question mark `?` doesn't make sense, remove it.

Comment: refers to a paging. url: (site.com/blog) (site.com/blog/P2). Thanks

Comment: I can not move '/' out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options here:

- Exclude it from the group, `P1` will be the contents in the capture group:

  ```
  $pattern = "#/(P[0-9])#";
  ```
- Use a lookbehind so that the `/` isn't even a part of the match, the entire match will be `P1`:

  ```
  $pattern = "#(?<=/)P[0-9]#";
  ```

Note that I also removed the `?` after your group because I don't think you actually want it, this makes the previous element optional so the regex `(/P[0-9])?` would match literal any string (it would match an empty string if `/P[0-9]` could not be matched).

Comment: @PapaCharlie Please provide a few examples of sample input and expected output.

Comment: preg_replace( "#BLOG(/P[0-9])#" , "$1" , "BLOG/P6" ); // output: /P6 // expected: 6

Comment: Try `preg_replace("#BLOG/(P[0-9])#", "$1", "BLOG/P6");` or `preg_replace("#BLOG/P([0-9])#", "$1", "BLOG/P6");`

Comment: the parameter /P(0-9) is optional and not always the url ends with '/'. ex: #1 (site.com/blog) or #2 (site.com/blog/p1). thanks again

Comment: This is very different from your original question... `preg_replace("#BLOG(?:/(P[0-9]))?#", "$1", "BLOG/P6");`

Comment: sorry for the poor explanation. Your help was amazing, worked perfect. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

With preg_* functions, you can use the `\K` trick that reset the begin of the match, example:

```
$pattern = '~/\KP[0-9]~';
```